# Ease-In animation once then linear

Tags: css

The following animation eases in, and after 4 seconds abruptly stops and eases in again and so on. Can this be made so that it just eases in once, then continues linearly?

```
-webkit-animation: move 4s ease-in 0s infinite;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could perform the ease-in animation just once and then have another linear animation start off (with delay) and perform infinite times;

depending on the type of animation it could work:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
   -webkit-animation: move 5s ease-in, move 5s linear 5s infinite; 
    animation: move 5s ease-in, move 5s linear 5s infinite;
 
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    50% {left: 200px;}
   100% {left: 0px;}
}

@keyframes move {
       0% {left: 0px;}
    50% {left: 200px;}
   100% {left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```